# convergence of functions.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, sequence-of-function

Let a sequence of functions $v_m$ that converges to $v$ in the space $L^{10/3}(\Omega)$, Where $\Omega$ is a bounded domain. Additionally, $\sup\limits_{m} |v_m|<C$, where $C$ is a constant.

Can I conclude that $v_m$ converges to $v$ in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Hint: What if $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$ and $v_m = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1/m]}$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that $\Omega$ is a bounded domain.

Comment: No, in general you only get weakly-star convergence.

Comment: @AndrésOrtiz The same example whpowell96 provided applies. Just change $\Omega$ to $[0, 1]$, say.

Comment: Think about what you are asking for. Take $\Omega=[0,1]$ and take the limit $v$ to be $\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$. Now, you know that continuous functions are dense in $L^{10/3}(\Omega)$. So, if what you were claiming were true, then you could find a sequence of continuous functions (which can easily be bounded) in $L^{\infty}$ norm to $\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$. That would imply that $\mathbf{1}_{[0,\frac{1}{2}]}$ is uniformly continuous.